# Automatic reboot after Ubuntu Livepatch

Tags: server, 22.04, canonical-livepatch, ubuntu-pro

When Ubuntu Livepatch has patched the kernel but recommends restarting to boot into the new version, a message appears in the motd like this:

```
*** Livepatch has fixed kernel vulnerabilities. System restart recommended on the closest maintenance window
```

It doesn't touch `/run/reboot-required`, even when `apt upgrade` has installed the new kernel.

I'm in the fortunate situation of having a weekly maintenance window, and I would like the system to reboot automatically when Livepatch recommends it. In other words, I want Livepatch's immediate patch functionality, but I don't need marathon uptime.

What's the best way of achieving this? As far as I can tell, there are four possibilities:

1. Is there a way to set Livepatch to touch `/run/reboot-required`?
2. Is there a way to set apt to touch `/run/reboot-required` after a kernel upgrade, even though Livepatch is active?
3. Is there a way to set unattended-upgrades to reboot when recommended by Livepatch, even when `/run/reboot-required` isn't present?
4. Is there a way to test whether Livepatch is recommending a restart, programmatically? `canonical-livepatch kernel-upgrade-required` appears to produce specific return codes, but these don't seem to be documented officially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described in the question is a (possibly unforeseen) side effect of a change made by Ubuntu to the unattended-upgrades package.

Until this issue is resolved by Ubuntu, the best workaround I've found is to use this script from current versions of Debian, which will restore usual reboot-required behaviour after kernel upgrades without taking account of Livepatch:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE::$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME" in
   linux-image-extra*::postrm)
      exit 0;;
esac

if [ -d /var/run ]; then
    touch /var/run/reboot-required
    if ! grep -q "^$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE$" /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs 2> /dev/null ; then
        echo "$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE" >> /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
    fi
fi
```

Details:

- Add it as a new file in the `/etc/kernel/postinst.d` directory (for example `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/x-user-unattended-upgrades`).
- In some circumstances it may duplicate functionality found in other kernel post-install hook scripts, but it will do so harmlessly.
- The system needs to have the unattended-upgrades package installed for the script to be useful.
- I've confirmed it's applicable for all recent versions of Ubuntu at time of writing. If you come to this answer at some point in the distant future, double-check it's still applicable and relevant.

[A bug has been registered concerning this issue in Launchpad.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/2017401)